# Does "authenticate with facebook" require a facebook-server to send data directly to my server?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am building a "authenticate with facebook" or "login with facebook" function for a website on my development server.
The development-server is a VM running on my computer.
I have set up my own DNS-server so that i can access the website with: anydomainname.de - which of course only works for me (not any external server).

Will i be able to test/develop the "authenticate with facebook" in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will i be able to test/develop the "authenticate with facebook" in this environment?

Yes, that should be no problem. (Done it lots of times myself already.)

Most of the login flow happens inside your browser anyway. And when it comes to the part of exchanging the `code` parameter you receive from Facebook for a token, that requires your server to make a request to Facebook, and not the other way around.

Only features that require Facebook servers to make a request to your server you won’t be to test that way, f.e. any kind of Open Graph implementation, where you host the OG objects yourself – that requires the FB scraper tool to read the meta data from the object URL, and therefor public access to it.

(Regarding login there is only one feature, called “De-authorize callback URL”, that you won’t be able to test. If you set that up, Facebook will notify you when users de-authorize your app [remove it from their settings completely] – and that is done by Facebook sending a request to your server. But that is kind of an “advanced” feature and not that broadly used anyway. Should you later on decide it would be nice to implement that as well, you will need to test it on a publicly available system.)